# Polynote notebook, import local scala file and import lib

Tags: scala, polynote

In Polynote notebook (https://polynote.org/), what is the syntax to load/import a local scala file with an Object inside?

Another question, how to load a maven/ivy lib? I used to use almond/ammonite/syntax, but it doesn't work.

`` import $ivy.`com.lihaoyi::requests:0.7.0` ``

Comment: These should be 2 separate questions. Ad 1) I believe it's not supported, you create/import/export whole notebooks and import whole dependencies. Ad 2) https://github.com/polynote/polynote/issues/720 .